# How to set parameters to ConferenceData to create event in Google Calendar API?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

A month ago I've have a code to create an event (I'm using credentials from *google service account* ) Its seem like this:

```
                eventExample.ConferenceData = new ConferenceData
                {
                    ConferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution
                    {
                        Key = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                        {
                            Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                        }
                    },
                    CreateRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest
                    {
                        RequestId = "qwerfsdiop",                        
                        ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                        {
                            Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    EntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>
                    {
                        new EntryPoint
                        {
                            EntryPointType = "video",                            
                        }
                    }                    
                };
```

Before create the event I set 1 to `ConferenceDataVersion` :

```
EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(eventExample, "example@gmail.com");

request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;
```

Now when I try to create the event I get this error: **Invalid conference type value** I think it's because of the update

I've searching and find this release from Google API Calendar:

> From now we require  `conferenceData` to be consistent with   `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type` ; meaning only
> Google Meet calls can have `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type` set to  `hangoutsMeet`. All 3P video conference providers are expected to set
> `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type` to  `addOn`.

I don't get it what means because I set the value `hangoutsMeet`  in my example and , anyone has an example to the rigth way to create the event after the update from January 11, 2021?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a call with the API and everything seemed fine.

The only error I see with your code is that you are informing to times the `key` (hangoutsMeet). But on of the times is wrong. Forget about the `conferenceData.conferenceSolution` and **for the creation** of the event only use the `createRequest` parameter.

This was my JSON request:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-05-28T09:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-05-28T08:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

And the previous message just worked completely fine.

The parameter of `conferenceData.conferenceSolution` only needs to be modify when you are [*patching the event*](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)

#### References

- [Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22conferenceDataVersion%22%3A1%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222021-05-28T09%3A00%3A00-07%3A00%22%7D%2C%22start%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222021-05-28T08%3A00%3A00-07%3A00%22%7D%2C%22conferenceData%22%3A%7B%22createRequest%22%3A%7B%22conferenceSolutionKey%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22hangoutsMeet%22%7D%2C%22requestId%22%3A%22hola%22%7D%7D%7D%7D#conferencing)